# Composite foreign key referencing 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, relational-database

I have created 3 tables `Student`, `Department` and `Major_in`.

I want to create a composite foreign key on (`email, Department_ID`) of `Major_in` that references the primary keys `email` of `Student` and `Department_ID` of `Department`.

```
CREATE TABLE Student
(
    email VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Department
(
    Department_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE Major_in 
(
    email VARCHAR(20), 
    Department_ID INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (roll, Department_ID) 
         REFERENCES (Student(email), Department(Department_ID)
);
```

But I get the error

> Error: near "(": syntax error`in`sqlite3`

Answer (score 1):

Figured out that doing this works, was a basic syntax error.

```
CREATE TABLE Major_in
(
    email REFERENCES Student, 
    Department_ID REFERENCES Department, 
    PRIMARY KEY (email, Department_ID)
);
```